# Network cards supporting PTP one-step-sync

Tags: linux, ptp

We currently want to setup a PTP Grandmaster using ptp4linux on a Linux host.
The slave devices rely on PTP one-step-sync but we haven't found any purchaseable network card on the marked which has this feature (ethtool has to report HWTSTAMP_TX_ONESTEP_SYNC).

We just found some phys (TI dp83640,Microchip LAN7430/1,Alaska 88E1512) which have this feature and are also supported by the Linux mainline kernel.

I am wondering if anyone knows PCIe/USB/... devices having these phys?
Or at least a network card which is one-step-sync capable or an embedded CoM/PC having these features?

Comment: relevant: OP's success report regarding a [Microchip LAN7430 PCIe card on the linuxptp mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/linuxptp/mailman/message/36600564/).